# Event Handling between classes in Java

Tags: java, event-handling

I have this class:

```
public class Registry {
    private ArrayList<Communication> communicationList;
    private ArrayList<Suspect> suspectList;
}
```

and at the main class, I add suspects:

```
registry.addSuspect(s1);
registry.addSuspect(s2);
registry.addSuspect(s3);
```

I have a class for a window `FindSuspect`, which has a text field and a button. How will it search for the suspect's name at the `registry.suspectList`? 
This class is inside FindSuspect class:

```
class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            //There will be an if statement here, which will check if the textField.getText() is a suspect inside
            //the registry.suspectList
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Suspect " + textField.getText() + " not found!"); 
        }
    }
```

I'm confused because the only registry item is at my main, so I don't have access to the suspect list from my FindSuspect class (where the buttonlistener is) which means I can't search for the suspect.

Comment: Using a loop? Or a stream? What's the concrete problem? What have you tried?

Comment: @JBNizet , When someone presses the button, I want it to search for the name into registry's suspect list and then show a message accordingly.

Comment: I understood that. But that doesn't answer my question. What's the concrete problem you faced when **trying** to do it?

Comment: I'm confused because the only registry item is at my main, so I don't have access to the suspect list from my FindSuspect class (where the buttonlistener is) which means I can't search for the suspect. (I'm totally new to Java. Sorry if it's something simple.)

Comment: OK, now it's clearer. You should say that in the question. Your main method should pass the registry as argument to the FindSuspect constructor, so that the FindSuspect object can store it in a field, and access it inside your listener.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your `Registry` class instance is available to access with the `actionPerformed` method and `Suspect` class has a field named `name`

You can add this code

```
boolean matchNotFound = registry.getSuspectList()
        .stream()
        .filter(s -> s.getName().equals(textField.getText()))
        .noneMatch();

if (matchNotFound) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Suspect " + textField.getText() + " not found!");
}
```

To get access to `Registry` in `FindSuspect` class there are multiple ways:

1. Mark it static in your Main class and access it here
2. Pass it as a parameter in ‘FindSuspect` constructor
3. Move it to another class that can be accessed from `FindSuspect`